# Complex SQL QUERY with DateDIFF

Tags: t-sql, datediff

I need to script a query to discard access logs that not exceeding a predetermined margin (eg. 2 seconds). That is, if each record was made by a user on a especific date / time, I don't want to get those who its date / time does not exceed the range compared with the date / time of the previous record. I think an example is clearer.

Example:

```
LogIndex, UserID, Date / Time

1. 01551, 20.02.2013 17:41:45.000
2. 01551, 20.02.2013 17:41:45.900 *
3. 01551, 20.02.2013 17:41:46.150 *
4. 01551, 20.02.2013 20:41:47.000

5. 01552, 02/20/2013 17:42:45.000
6. 01552, 20.02.2013 17:42:46.000 *
7. 01552, 02/20/2013 19:45:45.000 *
```

Records to discard because its date / time does not exceed the margin of 2 seconds over the previous record. In the first case two records should be discarted because both not exceed this margin.

Here's the code that creates the temporary table and adds the previous records to test:

```
CREATE TABLE # TEMP (LogIndex int, UserID nvarchar (10), LogTime datetime)

insert into # temp select 1, '01551 ', '20 / 02/2013 17:41:45.000'
insert into # temp select 2, '01551 ', '20 / 02/2013 17:41:45.900'
insert into # temp select 3, '01551 ', '20 / 02/2013 17:41:46.150'
insert into # temp select 4, '01551 ', '20 / 02/2013 20:41:47.000'
insert into # temp select 5, '01552 ', '20 / 02/2013 17:42:45.000'
insert into # temp select 6, '01552 ', '20 / 02/2013 17:42:46.000'
insert into # temp select 7, '01552 ', '20 / 02/2013 19:45:45.000'

select * from # temp

DROP TABLE # temp
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered solving the task the other way round?

You could create an `INSERT`-Trigger on the table which stores the accesslogs and reject data where time-difference to predecessor is smaller than you defined. It should be easier to get the last data saved per `userID` and compare it with the current one instead of writing a query which solves your task after data is collected.

You can also save those logs in a separate table via `INSERT`-Trigger ( I believe this data comes from access-control and therefore you're not allowed to delete those records, are you? )

Nevertheless, if you prefer to achieve things via query afterwards, try something like:

```
WITH "CTE" AS
(
    SELECT 
        T1.* 
        , diff = DATEDIFF( MS, T2.LogTime, T1.LogTime )
    FROM 
        #TEMP AS T1
        LEFT JOIN #TEMP AS T2
            ON 1 = 1
            AND T1.LogIndex = T2.LogIndex + 1
            AND T1.UserID = T2.UserID
)
, "ROLSUM" AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        , sumDiff = ( SELECT SUM(diff) FROM "CTE" AS C2 WHERE C2.LogIndex <= C1.LogIndex AND C2.UserId = C1.UserId )
    FROM
        "CTE" AS C1
)
SELECT 
    LogIndex, UserID, LogTime
FROM 
    ROLSUM
WHERE
    sumDiff > 2000 OR sumDiff IS NULL
```

Beware that this query is only a hint. It works with your demo-data but will fail if you add further data per `userID` which adds another bunch of data which should be rejected after a previous interval of valid and invalid data.

I'd prefer the first variant. Why storing data and process it afterwards, if you're able to get what you want much earlier and easier?!